# Meteor Subscription undefined in react component

Tags: meteor, reactjs, publish, subscribe

I am using meteor + react and am trying to subscribe to data on the client side. However, I keep getting the error that the collection I am trying to return is undefined.

My server.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Reminders = new Mongo.Collection('reminders');

Meteor.publish('reminders', function() {
    return Reminders.find();
});
```

My Reminders.jsx file:

```
RemindersList = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            reminders: [
                {
                    name: 'Pill 1',
                    description: 'Pill 1 description',
                    time: '9am'
                },

                 {
                    name: 'Pill 2',
                    description: 'Pill 2 description',
                    time: '9am'
                },

                 {
                    name: 'Pill 3',
                    description: 'Pill 3 description',
                    time: '9am'
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    getMeteorData: function() {

        var data = {};
        var handle = Meteor.subscribe('reminders');

        if(handle.ready()) {
          data.reminders = Reminders.findOne(); //Returns `Reminders` is not defined            

         }

        return data;

    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.data); //returns an empty object
        return (
            <h1>Test</h1>
        )
    }

});
```

The specific error I am getting is in the `getMeteorData` function:

`Reminders is not defined`.

However, I clearly define `Reminders` in my server.js file. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Your collection is only defined on server side. You'll need to put it in a file that's accessible on both sides and import it from both server and client side code.